# Can a Microsoft Power Fx formula calculate the sum of active related entities for the current record

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-platform

It's possible to calculate the total of related Task entities of Contacts using Microsoft Power FX, is this possible, and if so how?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/overview) didn't help to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either CountRows(.Tasks) or CountIf(Tasks, Task in .Tasks.Task) to find that. See an example below:
[image]